# Elementary OS 7 (Horus) compatibility with Ubuntu / Unity indicators on Pantheon's Wingpanel (top right menubar)?

Tags: wingpanel, desktop, pantheon, icons, horus

How can we display the "old" (and frequently still needed / required) system tray / indicator icons for apps like TeamViewer and so forth?

Without this, TeamViewer complains about it not being present and showing a warning that TeamViewer will run hidden. Other apps that are new or still updated need this functionality as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use my fork of Lafydevs project:

https://github.com/MvBonin/wingpanel-community-indicators

This is also up to date for elementary os 7.

The difference is, that there is a ... Indicator with a submenu of indicators and you can choose, where you want Indicators to be shown.

[image]

Its connected to https://github.com/MvBonin/switchboard-plug-indicators that adds a page to your settings app.

[image]

To install them, download the .dev files from my github repos and install them or follow the instructions on the github README.

Comment: Great to see, thanks! Your project was not showing up on any fork indicators. Can you give a more explicit installation process above? If not, I'll try to look more closely and edit your answer when I get a chance so as to make it quick and clear to step through the install.

Answer (score 2):

This can be restored by using the still functional [Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana) with the following steps:

(*Also note that active forks can be found with this [Active GitHub Forks project](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks) such as searching for the most recent forks of [elementary/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana) which led to [eth-p/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana](https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/#eth-p/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana) and then ultimately to Lafydev's most recently updated repository linked to initially above.*)

1. Open Terminal
2. Install developmental dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libindicator3-dev libwingpanel-dev indicator-application valac gcc meson git cmake
   ```
3. Get the repository:

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/dev/elementary_os
   git clone https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana.git ~/dev/elementary_os/lafydev_wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
   cd ~/dev/elementary_os/lafydev_wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
   ```
4. Build & install the repository:

   ```
   meson build --prefix=/usr
   cd build
   ninja
   sudo ninja install
   ```
5. Enable Pantheon autostart (after adding folder to home config autostart folder, modify .desktop file for system to add Pantheon as final entry and then copy file to home config):

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
   sudo sed -i 's/^OnlyShowIn.*/OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;Pantheon;/' /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop 
   cp /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop ~/.config/autostart/
   ```
6. Restart / Reboot system (`sudo reboot` if you like)
7. Enjoy:

   [image: example of wingpanel indicators restored]